# Webkit interface

Tags: webkit, delphi

I have been looking into webkit HTML offscreen rendering lately, but i am unable to find a Delphi library that wraps the webkit DLLs. I have tried using the Delphi Chromium package, which does "kinda" work  - but sadly there are a few quirks that have made me look for alternatives.

Does anyone know if there is a clean-cut, free, easy to use Delphi unit for webkit offscreen rendering?

Or is there a person fluent enough in Visual Studio/C++ who could write an import unit for it (you probably need to create a C wrapper around the C++ objects)?

Comment: I would have thought that it would be easier to make Delphi Chromium work rather than start from scratch. What exactly are the quirks?

Comment: And why is webkit mandatory? There are firefox kits, and obviously IE. Anyway, I would have a look at QT kits, since newer QT's (4.6+?) deliver webkit.

Comment: Well my project needs to render interfaces designed for mobile devices, which includes the custom webkit style headers. I also use the browser to render bitmaps of various controls in the background which are then transported to the GUI designer.

Comment: The problems with Delphi Chromium have to do with styling (see latest post to the Delphi chromium group), where you have to resize the browser form in order for the browser to update correctly. Also, the bitmaps you render are basically just a snapshot of the HDC.. which makes it cumbersome to work with (it can be tricky to calculate the height of a document without resorting to a JS callback).

Comment: It would be easier to write, oh, say: FWebKit.setSize(400,-1); FWebkit.Render(FFilename); FBitmap:=TBitmap.Create; FBitmap.Width:=400; FBitmap.Height:=FWebKit.RenderHeight;FWebkit.DrawTo(FBitmap,0,0);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since today, DCEF is able to make offscreen rendering using the TChromiumOSR component.
There is a demo in current SVN trunk that use Graphics32 paintbox component.
Be patient, good things take time.

Answer (score 0):

Well using QT (which contains webkit nowadays) you can apparently:

http://users.telenet.be/Jan.Van.hijfte/qtforfpc/fpcqt4.html

Note: this is for Lazarus QT apps. (and in the past Kylix). Also note the webkit in-app screenshot

Still, even while not ready to run with win32/64, it might give you a base of headers and how to wrap WebKit in a dll

Comment: Lazarus wraps QT, not webkit. And that would be overkill. It would be faster to translate the CSS myself and render it using GDI+. But i'll stick with chromium for now i guess, i can do some fixes in the code to get it working properly

Comment: The QT wrapper afaik also wraps webkit, since QT now contains webkit. If you can do it yourself, then I don't know why this question is specific to Chromium. Then other browsers (for which there are interfaces, most notably IE), are good too.

Comment: Yes, the QT wrapper does wrap webkit -- but then i have to ship X megabytes of extra dlls. The whole point of the question was to check if someone had an alternative route :)

Comment: And IE is out of the question. Perhaps the next version will support what everyone else supports - but i'm not about to rewrite 30kb lines of JS code just to please microsoft when everyone else (except firefox) supports it. The target product is mobile, which excludes IE and firefox (sadly, i use firefox myself).